# Netty ByteBuf write and read

Tags: netty

I don't fully understand how ByteBuf's write and read methods are actually working under the hood. A detailed explanation of both methods would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for. I think the javadocs of it is quite detailed. Please be more specific what exactly you need more details on.

Answer (score 0):

ByteBuf is just a container for message bytes,whether the data you write to the other side or data you receive from others.
The memory allocated for a ByteBuf may be direct or indirect, so for application in high level, the user just need to use the corresponding write and read api,without worry about the real format of the instance.